# Problems with jQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to query a MySQL database and put the result in jQuery using JSON, because I need to do graphics.

**My problem is when I manipulate the JSON.**

My code at the moment:
**index.php**

```
$(function ($) {

    $("#formulario").submit(function () {

        var nome = $("#nome").val();

        $("#status").html("<img src='loader.gif' alt='Enviando' />");
        $.post('envia.php', {
            nome: nome
        }, function (resposta) {
            $("#status").slideDown();
            if (resposta != false) {
                $("#status").html(resposta);
            } else {
                $("#nome").val("");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**envia.php** (the query is only for test)

```
require_once("conecta.php");

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$culturas = array();
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select *from mandioca_iea where  mandioca_iea_id=1");

while ($cultura = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    array_push($culturas, $cultura);
}

echo json_encode($culturas);
```

If I test the code in this way:
In div="status" appears:

> [{"mandioca_iea_id":"1","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0","man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0","man_ins_area_13":"0","man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"1","id_cult":"1"}]
>   **OK,It works**

But when I try to access the "fields" using this code, it doesn't work:

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {
    for(var i=0; i<resposta.length; i++) {
        var registro = resposta[i];
        console.log(registro.man_ins_area_10); 
    }
});
```

OBS: I tried `resposta = $.parseJSON(resposta)` too.

In console of web browser, the result is:

228 undefined, in other words, happens "loop" 228 times and all "vars" are undefined.

Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: because there is no `iea_id` in the json data.

Comment: Your response object does not contain a `iea_id` field.

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira I think you tried to parse it in a wrong way. 
Try this inside $.post function: `var registro = JSON.parse(resposta);` and then try `console.log(registro.man_ins_area_10);`

Answer (score 1):

try with proper `attribute`.since there is no `iea_id` in your `json data` it is not giving anything.

```
 var resposta= [{"mandioca_iea_id":"1","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0","man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0","man_ins_area_13":"0","man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"1","id_cult":"1"}] 
     for(var i=0; i<resposta.length; i++) {
            var registro = resposta[i];
            console.log(registro.mandioca_iea_id); //it should give 1
        }
```

**updated:**

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {
    console.log(resposta);
    var resposta=JSON.parse(resposta);
    for(var i=0; i<resposta.length; i++) {
        var registro = resposta[i];
        console.log(registro.customerLat); 
    }
});
```

Comment: if the var "reposta"  coming from php,to be continued "228 undefined",

Comment: sorry i did not get you what exactly you are trying to ask.

Comment: I haven't 10 points of reputation then i can't post image. But when i test the code with "var resposta= [{"mandioca_iea_id":"1","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0","man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0","man_ins_area_13":"0","man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"1","id_cult":"1"}]" works fine.
When i retreat,this line setting resposta(as it was before), not work.
I don't know why :/

Comment: The error now is(" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Comment: try the updated one and start debugging the data using `console.log()` or `console.info()`.

Answer (score 0):

edit: in addition to the comments "no iea_id field".
can you try this? i added the "json" part

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {
            $("#status").slideDown();
            if (resposta != false) {
                $("#status").html(resposta);
            } 
            else {
                $("#nome").val("");
            }
},
"json" //this specifies that the result is a json object
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringify your post data parameter.

```
//stringify your json post data parameters
var postData=JSON.stringify({nome: nome});
$.post('envia.php', postData, function(resposta) {
    //parse received json string
    resposta= $.parseJSON(resposta);
    for(var i=0; i<resposta.length; i++) {
        var registro = resposta[i];
        console.log(registro.man_ins_area_10); 
    }
});
```